# Why does GORM create a custom id when I specify primary key manually?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I've got a GORM model:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name, PhotoId, Bio  string
    ChatId              int64 `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Gender, Orientation int
}
```

As you can see, I'm specifying the primary key manually. But when I check the table GORM created:

```
postgres=# \d users
                                          Table "public.users"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 updated_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 deleted_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 name        | text                     |           |          | 
 photo_id    | text                     |           |          | 
 bio         | text                     |           |          | 
 chat_id     | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('users_chat_id_seq'::regclass)
 gender      | integer                  |           |          | 
 orientation | integer                  |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, chat_id)
    "idx_users_deleted_at" btree (deleted_at)
```

I can see that GORM also added `id` column which is used as key as well. Why does it happen? Does it mean that when I do something like this:

```
var user User
db.First(&user, 1)
```

Gorm will look for the user with `id=1` instead of `chat_id=1`?

Comment: Because you're using `gorm.Model` which also defines a primary key field, namely `ID uint \`gorm:"primary_key"\``. If you want a custom non-composite primary key then you'll have to remove the embedded `gorm.Model` from your `User` type.

Comment: @mkopriva oh, I thought that it was necessary for gorm to have it in the struct. Thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that removing `gorm.Model` also removes the 3 timestamp fields, so if you need any of those timestamps you'll have to define them explicitly in your `User` type.

Answer (score 1):

As @mkopriva said in the comments, `gorm.Model` adds the id column. If I remove it from struct definition, table is created as expected:

```
postgres=# \d users
                  Table "public.users"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 name        | text    |           |          | 
 photo_id    | text    |           |          | 
 bio         | text    |           |          | 
 chat_id     | bigint  |           | not null | 
 gender      | integer |           |          | 
 orientation | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (chat_id)
```